# Update Linked Server Tables Using Synonyms

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server, insert-update, synonym

I have a server in a remote location and Its now connected to my local server through Linked Server. How can I update a table at remote location without using stored procedures.

1. Would SQL Synonyms be any kind of help?
2. Does user need to have Write permission on the Remote Server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something seems off here. Why is the requirement to "update the remote location without using stored procedures"? You can update data in a table on a linked server with an `UPDATE` statement. Do you mean something other than DML?

Answer (score 0):

You would use an update statement. Not sure why the requirement to not use a stored procedure comes from. I am concerned that you believe that somehow a stored procedure would make this easier in some way.

**1)** Synonyms are not going to help or hinder this process. They are simply a way to shorthand an object name.

**2)** Of course the user for the linked server connection must have write permission to write data.

Comment: I can not do any modification to database schema as i have already handed over the product to client. So I am planning to run a SQL Job on a remote server to do modification to the data.

Comment: OK. Have you tried anything? Seems a little strange that you need to make changes like this. In most situations this would be considered a software update. They are pretty common and expected.

Comment: If you have handed over the code, then why would you still have access permission? 
How would you set up linked server incase if the change credentials and not letting you know?

Comment: That sounds like a recipe for disaster. If you need to deploy changes to a client database then you need to go through the process of deployment (schedule downtime, bring db offline, deploy, bring online, test, user testing, etc.). Why would you want to "backdoor" this?